# ANTLRWorks compiling

Tags: antlrworks

I am using ANTLRWorks 1.5 and am trying to compile and debug. Sometimes I get the following error while compiling:

---

```
[11:44:52] TODO: run and send output to this console
[11:44:56] C:\Antlr\output\tryParser.java:102: error: <identifier> expected
[11:44:56]  public final tryParser.poly_return poly() throws  {
[11:44:56]                                                  ^
[11:44:56] C:\Antlr\output\tryParser.java:215: error: <identifier> expected
[11:44:56]  public final tryParser.term_return term() throws  {
[11:44:56]                                                  ^
[11:44:56] C:\Antlr\output\tryParser.java:504: error: <identifier> expected
[11:44:56]  public final tryParser.exp_return exp() throws  {
[11:44:56]                                                ^
[11:44:56] 3 errors
```

---

Can anyone tell me what does this error mean?

Sometimes it compiles without any problem but I always get the 'timeout' error in debugging.

My code is:

---

```
grammar try;
options {output=AST;}
tokens { MULT; } // imaginary token

poly: term ('+'^ term)*
;

term: INT ID  -> ^(MULT["*"] INT ID)
| INT exp -> ^(MULT["*"] INT exp)
| exp
| INT
| ID
;
exp : ID '^'^ INT
;

ID  : 'a'..'z'+ ;
INT : '0'..'9'+ ;
WS  : (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')+ {skip();} ;
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you need to update to ANTLRWorks 1.5.2.

[Issue #5: ANTLRworks fails to generate proper Java Code](https://github.com/antlr/antlrworks/issues/5)